# Spacing between some words is just too big in mobile view when text is justified

Tags: html, css

I made a website and I was ready to launch it but then I noticed that when displayed on mobile certain words in text have just too big spacing between them. Is it possible to somehow define maximum spacing in paragraph?

[image: spacing problem]

```
p {
  text-align:justify;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Justifying text is dangerous for exactly this reason. Sometimes you just cannot justify without creating huge gaps in the text. The LaTeX compiler actually prefers extending the line (ignoring e.g. page margins) instead of creating holes.

You could try the `hyphens` CSS property to *avoid* gaps, but keep in mind that this feature is new and might not always work. See https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/hyphenate/

You’d have to adjust the font size or width of your container or edit the text if you absolutely have to avoid these gaps. But keep in mind to test many resolutions, screen widths, and zoom factors. You’re probably too busy to follow this approach, so there is no feasible solution other than left-aligning your text or biting the bullet and live with the gaps.

Answer (score -2):

If you keep `text-align: justify` it isn't possible.

Once you have removed it, just use `word-spacing`

Here some examples

```
word-spacing: normal;
word-spacing: 5em;
word-spacing: 15px;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-spacing

Comment: And if you're using bootstrap, you could include a ```.hidden-xs``` and a ```.visible-xs-*``` to allow two different styling options for different screen sizes.

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_helpers.asp

Comment: That doesn't work. It sets the *minimum* spacing, `text-align: justify` will still expand the spacing so that the left and right edges of the text are both straight.

Comment: This doesn’t help if the browser needs to put the words further apart in order to achieve justification.

Comment: The question is "Is it possible to somehow define maximum spacing in paragraph?" and I answered correctly